# Cakephp updates have no effect until changing the debug mode to 2

Tags: cakephp

I've had a few situations that after commiting the updated code to the production server only visual changes took effect (in my case it was saving a value in the database) but the application acted like there was no code updates at all.

After commiting the debug mode to 2 and then back to 0 it started working.

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the debug mode is set to 1 or 2, the CakePHP cache is refreshed on every request. This makes for instance models updates visible.

When the debug mode is set to 0, Cake does not refresh the cache and some updates may not be available.

When putting some code updates in production, you should always delete the content of the `app/tmp` folder. (but not the `app/tmp` subfolders as they are not recreated automatically)

From the Cookbook: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/deployment.html#update-core-php , when debug is set to 0:

> Core CakePHP caches are flushed every 99 years, instead of every 10 seconds as in development.